BytesRequired number of elements overflowed when Tensorflow Lite inferencing
I was trying to convert rtmpose body2d onnx file to tensorflow lite format from here https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmpose/tree/main/projects/rtmpose#body-2d
I was succesfully converting to saved model file and it works on inferencing. But when I convert saved model to tflite format and testing I got a error like this,
Interpreter successfully created.
Error allocating tensors: tensorflow/lite/util.cc BytesRequired number of elements overflowed.
Node number 183 (MAX_POOL_2D) failed to prepare.Failed to apply the default TensorFlow Lite delegate indexed at 0.

Here is method for onnx to saved model:
def convert_onnx_to_saved_model():
    # Load the ONNX model
    model = onnx.load("model.onnx")

    tf_rep = prepare(model)
    tf_rep.export_graph("model")

Here is method for saved model to tflite:
def convert_saved_model_to_tflite():
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("model")

    # Convert the model
    tflite_model = converter.convert()

    # Save the model to a file
    with open("model.tflite", "wb") as f:
        f.write(tflite_model)

Here is inferencing method:
def load_and_test_tflite(model_path):
    try:
        # Load the TFLite model
        interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
        print("Interpreter successfully created.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading model: {e}")
        return

    try:
        # Allocate tensors
        interpreter.allocate_tensors()
        print("Tensors successfully allocated.")
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print(f"Error allocating tensors: {e}")
        return

    # Get input and output details
    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

    print("Input details:", input_details)
    print("Output details:", output_details)

    # Create dummy input tensor
    input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
    input_data = np.random.random_sample(input_shape).astype(np.float32)

    try:
        # Set the input tensor
        interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

        # Run inference
        interpreter.invoke()
        print("Inference successfully run.")
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print(f"Error during inference: {e}")
        return

    try:
        # Get the output tensor
        output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
        print("Output data:", output_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting output tensor: {e}")

Here input and output details:
Input details: [{'name': 'serving_default_input:0', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([  1,   3, 256, 192]), 'shape_signature': array([ -1,   3, 256, 192]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
Output details: [{'name': 'PartitionedCall:0', 'index': 398, 'shape': array([  1,   1, 384]), 'shape_signature': array([ -1,  -1, 384]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name': 'PartitionedCall:1', 'index': 399, 'shape': array([  1,   1, 512]), 'shape_signature': array([ -1,  -1, 512]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]

Where is the problem in my tflite model? Thank you.

I got the same error after converting. Input of rtmpose is dynamic if remember correctly it is [batch, 3, 194 , 256]
fix the batch to 1 or any fixed number, tf-lite does not support dynamic input layer.
When you convert the pytorch model to onnx you must be using this config file "configs/mmpose/pose-detection_simcc_onnxruntime_dynamic.py"
change it to this instead

base = ['./pose-detection_static.py', '../base/backends/onnxruntime.py']
onnx_config = dict(
input_shape=[192, 256],
output_names=['simcc_x', 'simcc_y'],
)
codebase_config = dict(
export_postprocess=False   )


I got still same error with this :(
target_input_shape = [1, 3, 256, 192]
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(input_details[0]['index'], target_input_shape, strict=True)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
print("Tensors successfully allocated.")

I will add input output detail to my question.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

i was not clear change the input layer of the model, not just the input tensor

change the input layer of your onnx model instead of batch fix to a intiger number(i fixed it to 1) then convert it to tf and then tf-lite.
when you convert a model with dynamic input size layer in tf-lite that create issue, that is how i did it
